# multi thread slower than single thread in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3, mutex

I am trying to benchmark the below code,

the method Rate.rate_by_service, does some DB calls / processing and returns a value

```
mutex = Mutex.new
thread_arr = []
puts Benchmark.measure{
1000.times do |i|
  services.each_with_index do |service_obj,index|
    thread_arr[index] = Thread.new {
      mutex.synchronize {
        rate << Rate.rate_by_service(service_obj,@package,@from,@to,@credentials) #does database calls / calcualtions and returns a value
      }
    }
    #rate << 
  end
  thread_arr.each {|t| t.join}
end
}
```

The strange thing i have observed is that the multi threaded version is slower that the regular version(without threads)

Here are the benchmarking results.

```
 #threading
 4.870000   0.490000   5.360000 (  6.846712)
 5.300000   0.520000   5.820000 (  7.550946)
 4.640000   0.480000   5.120000 (  6.720078)
 4.580000   0.460000   5.040000 (  6.344415)
 4.510000   0.450000   4.960000 (  6.312238)




#no threading
3.610000   0.240000   3.850000 (  4.088772)
3.360000   0.200000   3.560000 (  3.721254)
3.380000   0.190000   3.570000 (  3.795252)
3.500000   0.200000   3.700000 (  4.156553)
3.580000   0.210000   3.790000 (  4.183601)
```

is there something wrong that I am doing? Can anyone please elaborate as to why this behaviour could be happening.

**I am using ruby 2.0, rails Rails 4.2.7.1**

Comment: The mutex emsures that your logic `Rate.rate_by_service` will be executed sequentielly but adds threading overhead. Without the mutex, it should faster. ;-)

Comment: but then won't it cause some values to be inconsistent? i.e. by removing mutex

Comment: Depends on your implementation of `Rate.rate_by_service`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole executable block of every `Thread` is synchronized, making the code *fully synchronous*, but introducing an overhead on thread creation and context switch. What did you expect?

To make it asynchronous, one should synchronize the original array update only:

```
1000.times do |_|
  services.map do |service_obj|
    Thread.new do
      result = Rate.rate_by_service(...)
      mutex.synchronize { rate << result }
    end
  end.each(&:join)
end
```

Notice that the database query, `Rate.rate_by_service`, is made outside of the mutex synchronize.

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa, but when i do as above, mutex.synchronize {rate << result} i get "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ServiceOption"

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the original question that was about why for this code multiple `Thread`s are not as performant as a single one.

Comment: i updated the code to how you sufggsted but still non-threading mode is faster. Could it be because of Active record cache? i see many results being fetched from cache in non-threading mode.

Comment: I have updated the questions with new readings post removing mutex

Comment: Cache? `ActiveRecord`? Are you kidding me? I am not a fortuneteller and not a spiritualist. Also, please immediately stop updating the question inplace after you have an answer received.

Comment: Hi Sorry, but i just want to clear my understanding, I did as you said, but I see difference, i just want to understand it better

Comment: If you have any other question, don’t hesitate to ask _a new other question_. This site is not a service to help you, what matters is a consistency between questions and answers for future readers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160514/discussion-between-opensource-developer-and-mudasobwa).